# Create KML file from Metro Dreamin map

Tags: javascript, kml, mapbox, ipad

I am wondering if there is an easy way to create a KML file from a Metrodreamin.com map; perhaps from a JSON file. Ideally I would like to do this from an Ipad. However I have acess to a Windows desktop as well.

I tried to see if I could find a Mapbox mapid using Google Chrome Dev tools so I could use a Git Hub web app to convert to KML but it appears that doesn't work (a JS script says mapid=n)

Answer (score -1):

Google Chrome Dev tools can set breakpoint.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/

Give this a try see if you can see the mapid

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).